# object HTMLInputElement jquery error

Tags: jquery

I am making a admin edit area... where i can edit already exist admin. I have made create admin very successfully using this type of function method but now ... everything is working fine but when i save values in database. it saves values at [object HTMLInputElement] no matter what i gave value to the input fields.

SQL database query working fine but i dont know where is the problem  here is my jquery function. There may be some other error but i want someone to point me what cause [object HTMLInputElement] type of thing thanks.

```
function  edit_admin(){
var admin_eidt = $("#admin_eidt") .val();
var afn_edit = $("#afn_edit") .val();
var aemail_edit = $("#aemail_edit") .val();
var apass_edit = $("#apass_edit") .val();
var edit_admin_chk = [];
var vpb_amenities_actual;
$.each($('.edit_admin_chk'), function()
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        edit_admin_chk.push($(this).val());
    }
});
if(admin_eidt == "" || afn_eidt == "" || aemail_eidt == "" || apass_eidt == "" ){
    _("error_admin").style.display = "block";
    $("#parkerror_admin").fadeIn().html("Admin informaiton  is missing");
    }else{
    $("#error_admin").hide();
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "edit_admin.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
             if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
        _("error_admin").style.display = "none";
        _("error_admin").style.display = "block";
        $("#parkerror_admin").fadeIn().html("Updated Successfully");
        $("#numbtn_admin").show();
        $("#errorzz_admin").hide();
        }else{
        _("error_admin").style.display = "block";
        $("#parkerror_admin").fadeIn().html(ajax.responseText);
        $("#numbtn_admin").show();
                 }
}           }
    }

ajax.send("admined=" + admin_eidt + "&edit_admin_chk=" + edit_admin_chk + "&afned=" + afn_eidt+ "&aemailed=" +aemail_eidt+"&apassed=" + apass_eidt );
}
```

Comment: what does console.log(admin_eidt); show..?

Comment: Some html might offer insights. Also, what is the output when you alert, say, admin_edit?

Comment: alert says edited successfully....